# Equal height columns width issue

Tags: html, css, width, multiple-columns

I have 3 columns that extend to equal height. The only problem now is that if I have 2 columns only they expand their width and take 100% of the main container. So basically I need them to have the same width wether it's 1, 2 or 3 columns.
Any idea on how to achieve this?
Many thanks!

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rfjg4/)**

```
.content > img {
    vertical-align:top;
}
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display:table;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-spacing: 30px;
}
#wrapper > .col {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30.3%;
    margin: 0 15px 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#wrapper > .col > .content {
    padding:0 0 35px;
    height:100%;
}
.content {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    position: relative;
}
.content > p {
    vertical-align:top;
}
.content h3 {
    font-size:1.375rem;
    font-weight:400;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 25px 27px 0;
}
.content p {
    text-align:left;
    padding: 0 27px 30px;
}
.button.moreinfo {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
    padding-right: 0.3rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
    padding-left: 0.3rem;
    background-color: #2a2a2a;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    color: #f39c12;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
}
div.btn-align-bottom {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:50px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.info-box {
    margin-bottom:0;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.info-box img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.info-box-inner {
    background: #FFF;
    padding:25px 27px 35px;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:none;
    min-height:270px;
    text-align:center;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(48, 48, 48, 0.3);
    z-index:1;
}
.info-box-inner p {
    text-align:left;
}
.info-box-inner h3 {
    font-size:1.375rem;
    font-weight:400;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: So you want to set a fixed width on the columns in pixesl? Is that right?

Comment: So just add a max-width in pixels...does that not work? However, I'm not seeing the point of using display:table in that case.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't work.

Comment: I would remove all of the `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;` bits and use floats instead.

Comment: On the contrary ``display:table`` and ``display:table-cell`` are very handy, if you want equal height for all boxes...

Comment: @Paulie_D : http://jsfiddle.net/mupj2/ to get u started :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally [here is my working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rfjg4/10/). See http://jsfiddle.net/rfjg4/10/show/ for the result.

I added the class `col2` to the second wrapper and the CSS:

```
.wrapper.col2:after {
    content: "";
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30.3%;
    margin: 0 15px 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

With the above code a new cell with empty content is added to the `<div class="wrapper col2">` tag.

Alternatively you can avoid the `col2` by using CSS 3 selectors:

```
wrapper:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ div::after {
    content: "";
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30.3%;
    margin: 0 15px 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfjg4/11/) or http://jsfiddle.net/rfjg4/11/show/ for an example. (See this Stackoverflow question [Can CSS detect the number of children an element has?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720931/can-css-detect-the-number-of-children-an-element-has) for explanation of the selectors).

Some notes:

- In your jsFiddle example you used two times `id="wrapper"` for a `<div>`. You have to change the `id` to a `class` (and update your CSS)
- There is one `</div>` extra in line 17 (and in other lines, too). Those tags are marked red in jsFiddle.
- You do not need `position:relative;` in your CSS (I deleted it in the example).

Comment: This fiddle behaves identically as the one OP provided.  Maybe I'm mistaken, but I believe he is having an issue trying to get the two bottom cols to remain at the same width as the top three, even though there are only two of them.  To me, it looks like an issue with the `display: table-cell;` bit of the CSS.

Comment: You can see just a difference after you make the iframe for the jsFiddle bigger than certain amount (have a look [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rfjg4/2/show/) on a big screen)

Comment: I made it larger, when I originally viewed it.  Your fiddle still behaves in the same manner as his, which is what I originally said.  In your fiddle, the bottom two columns still expand to a total width of 100%, which is the situation the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @JohnManly: You are right! Thanks for clarification, I guess now I understand the problem... ;-)

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Thanks John Manly for the clarification

Comment: We're almost there. I've found out that for some reason when you add a 3rd column to the second row all the bottom columns qet too narrow

Comment: Then you have to remove ``class="col2"`` from the second wrapper and everything is fine...

Comment: (Reason: with ``class="col2"`` a new cell is added to the wrapper at the end of the ``<div>``)

Comment: Oh I see. But isn't there a way to avoid that? I mean if the user adds an extra column then he will have to remove that extra class to the wrapper. Not really what I'm looking for

Comment: See my update of the question (just works with the new CSS3 selectors). See http://caniuse.com/ for the browser support. Alternatively you can also use jQuery (requires obviously JavaScript).